# Need users to insert values in a Reporting Services Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, pasting

I need users to be able to paste a list of values (all for one column) into a reporting services report.

This list will then be inserted into a temp table and that temp table left joined to my query.

The resultset I am looking for is a count of NULLs to indicate how many of those values (they're IDs) are missing in the database and how many are present. From there, it will also be returning the details of the available IDs.

I can do the second part, but am struggling to be able to enter a list (say, 50 rows) into a temp table via Reporting Services.

The end user does not have access to SQL and will preferably need to do little adjustment to their values (adding brackets etc.) before pasting into the Report Parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind that parameters have a maximum length of 2000 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a table valued function that takes two parameters a varchar(max) string and a delimiter. In the function parse the string on the supplied delimiter into rows.

   ```
   create FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_MakeTableFromLIst]
   (
   @LIST varchar(max), 
   @DELIMITER char(1)= ','
   )

   RETURNS @RETURN_TABLE TABLE (Param varchar(4000))

   AS 
   BEGIN

   Declare @POS int,
   @PIECE varchar(4000)

   Set @LIST = ltrim(rtrim(@LIST)) + @DELIMITER
   Set @POS = charindex(@DELIMITER, @LIST, 1)

   -- parse the string into a table
   if REPLACE(@LIST, @DELIMITER, '') <> ''
   begin

   WHILE @POS > 0
   begin

   SET @PIECE = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@LIST, @POS - 1)))
   IF @PIECE <> ''
       begin

       INSERT INTO @RETURN_TABLE (param) VALUES (CAST(@PIECE AS varchar(4000)))

       end

   SET @LIST = RIGHT(@LIST, LEN(@LIST) - @POS)
   SET @POS = CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER, @LIST, 1)

   END
   End
   RETURN
   ```
2. Create two parameters in you report to accept a delimited string and the delimiter. The client will then be able to supply you with a format that they have available as long as they have a consistent delimiter in the string.
3. Do your left or right join and count up your nulls.

Comment: SELECT [Param] AS OrderID INTO #a FROM ServerName.[dbo].[ufn_MakeTableFromList](@LIST,@DELIMITER)

Comment: Usually I will  use something like    join (select * from ufn_GetTableFromList(@PACKAGE,','))    you can also do a left or right to isolate the null values from the given table.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a multi valued parameter in the report which will fetch the list of all ID's and user will be select as per their wishes. Else u can provide a plain textbox parameter where they will type all the ID's with say comma separeted.

Later u can call a Proc with this parameter values and do what u want to do in the proc. Let me know if this helps you.